How can I maintain the current delivered by a power source constant if the load is variable?
Fig. 1 shows, in a simplified way, a DC power source that unfortunately can only work if the current drawn from it is constant and has a given value "I", otherwise this source will wear quickly due to its construction.
This source has to feed a useful load that varies in time. I guess that, in order to keep the current "I" constant, I have to use a microcontroller controlled dump load that, based on the measured current drawn by the useful load, will absorb such a current as to keep "I" constant.
Question: Can you suggest a schematic for the dump load?

Fig. 1. Variable useful load and DC power source that only works at a constant voltage and current.
UPDATE:
Maybe the schematic in Fig. 2 is more clear. Basically what I want is that DC to DC convertor (preferably a high power one).

Fig. 2. The same configuration as in Fig. 1 above but with the Dump Load replaced by a DC to DC convertor with a fix dissipation resistor R connected at its output.

What is the power source?

@MOSFET The power source is a helicopter gas turbine (that has to work at constant speed otherwise it wears quickly) that through a gearbox turns a high frequency electric generator. An AC to DC power converter outputs DC power that is taken by an ensemble of electric motors which makes the useful load. However please disregard this complication. Consider that the power source is like a battery obliged to deliver a constant current. Also consider that the battery is of reduced power like say 100 - 500 W.

The turbine needs to work at a constant speed, ok. But does it need to be at a constant torque? That is, can the power input (fuel) be varied depending on the load, while maintaining the same RPM, such as what a diesel genset does?

This doesn't seem right. What happens if the turbine runs at constant speed, so it doesn't wear, but the output is open circuit?

We go to nowhere. Please disregard the fact that the power source is a turbine. This turbine has protection mechanisms. Its speed can be varied, the torque can be varied. The problem is that in normal working conditions the power it delivers has to be constant. If you change the torque/speed of the turbine all the time it will not have a long life.

We go to nowhere because you never answered my question. No one suggested you change the speed or the torque. Also, you are now stating the "power it delivers has to be constant". This is in contrast from the posted question. TBH, I don't think you understand your problem well enough. Or you're not disclosing relevant information. See XY problem.

The power delivered by the turbine is constant. A part of it is absorbed by the useful load and the other by the dump load. The sum of the two powers has to be constant.

What's the operating voltage range of your turbine? And current? You already mentioned the power range is 100W to 500W.

You can take, for example, the voltage across the battery in Fig. 1 as 12 V and the current 8.33 Amp (power 100 W).

Here's how you waste power to keep the source power delivery constant using a microcontroller:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You sample the 2 ADC's via firmware and multiply these values together to get power. If power < 100W, increase DAC. If power > 100W, decrease DAC. Recalculate. Loop.
Obviously you will have to come up with a stable PID algorithm to suit your specific use case. And the circuit will likely have to be tailored for the same reason. But the theory remains the same.

Perhaps less obviously, you need to find a transistor and cooling system to dissipate 500 watts continuously.

@vir That's not my problem. There are a bunch of details and requirements missing. The schematic is only conceptual. For example, the design might require highside current sensing. TBH, the whole idea seems dubious from the onset - I'm intrigued by this generator that requires adding inefficiency by design.

To design the PID I can recommend PID Without a PhD by our very own SE user Tim Wescott

It's cheaper to burn power in resistors than in semiconductors, so let's use PWM on a resistive dump load.

V1 is the source from which a constant current must be drawn. Here the target current is 5A.
E1 models a sense amplifier which measures current on sense resistor R1. An error signal is created, which is the difference between target current and actual current. This is integrated, and drives a PWM modulator (sawtooh and comparator). This drives a MOSFET to switch a resistor dump load.
I1 is a variable load for testing.
The result is that the average current drawn from V1 is constant. Since the source includes a rectifier, I assume there are also smoothing caps, which will also smooth the current.
This can be implemented in analog, or in a microcontroller.
Note that drawing constant current will keep torque constant on the generator, but it will not keep RPM constant: if the current setpoint is a bit too high or a bit too low, and it always will, then RMP will keep decreasing or increasing.
If you want this circuit to keep generator RPM constant instead, then you need to make it into a shunt regulator, keeping V1 constant. This is not complicated: either use a hysteresis comparator to switch a resistor dump load, or use the same PWM circuit with the input being voltage instead of current.

Thank you for your schematic. One question: I know that the power is Torque x RPM. If the RPM of the generator increases or decreases continuously, while the torque stays constant, then the power generated will converge to the maximum possible power or to zero. Neither of these two cases appears to be a practical solution.

That is correct, that's why I think what you're asking in the question (constant current) may not actually be what you need to achieve your true goal... which considering the information you gave, seems a bit mysterious at the moment...
